# Adding Facebook feed of posts to website

Tags: facebook, rss, feed

A client has asked that a summary of their Facebook posts appears on their website. I can add my own personal "[Activity Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity)", but I can't figure out how to (a) Add my client's feed to their site (b) show all their posts, rather than what is considered to be "interesting" activity.

I used to be able to create this from an RSS feed of their posts, but an RSS feed no longer appears to be available. There used to be a script that does this, but that no longer works.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. My client is not that technical, so suggesting that they create an app is a non-starter.

Comment: What about the [Facebook Like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages) ? It embeds a feed of content from a Facebook Page into a website

Comment: So it does! Though it is not very customizable. I'd like to show just the post headlines, rather than the whole post, but a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The RSS 2.0 feed is still there (but will be deprecated soon), but not the JSON feed. See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1539780319626180/

Example:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=7146002927&format=rss20